# ContentType of an Entry in chrome file system api

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm using chrome file system API. Would like to find the contentType of the selected file.

Sample code snippet

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'openFile', accepts: accepts, acceptsMultiple: true }, function(theEntry, fileEntries) {
                  var fileCount = theEntry.length;....
                 //.... theEntry.contentType (Something like this)..........
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileEntry#File

Comment: @DanielHerr, He's talking about chrome apps, not HTML5 filesystem.

Comment: @Pacerier The Chrome Apps Filesystem api is integrated with the Web Filesystem api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FILE_ENTRY.file()` method. It's asynchronous, so you'll have to check manually whether the last element is being processed.

```js
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({
    type: 'openFile',
    acceptsMultiple: true
}, function(entries) {
    var files = [];
    entries.forEach(function(entry, i, entries) {
        var isLast = i == entries.length - 1;
        entry.file(
            function(file) { // success callback
                files.push(file);
                if (isLast) {
                    processAll(files);
                }
            },
            function(file) { // error callback
                console.error('error', file);
                if (isLast) {
                    processAll(files);
                }
            }
        );
    });
});

function processAll(files) {
    files.forEach(function(file) {
        console.log(file.name, file.type);
    });
}
```

Notes:

- [File API specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/).
- Chrome's File System API sets MIME type for well-known file types only.
  Clipboard and File INPUT elements recognize all MIME types.
  Source: [chromium code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/fileapi/File.h?sq=package:chromium&dr=CSs&rcl=1469244486&l=49) (click `AllContentTypes` to see where it is used).